# How will I access inner fields values in twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I want to access 'name' key in the given image, but when I am trying with this 
`author_picture['#user'].contents.name` its showing nothing.

[image]

Comment: `contents` is the title of the debugger tab (not part of the variable), you just want `author_picture['#user'].name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question for the node id from today [Reason for adding .value to access node id?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259713/reason-for-adding-value-to-access-node-id)

Either add `.value` to the field name

```
{{ author_picture['#user'].name.value }}
```

or use a specific method if the entity provides one:

```
{{ author_picture['#user'].getdisplayname }}
```

It is preferable to use  [User:getDisplayName](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetDisplayName/8.5.x) because it does extra processing:

> By default, the passed-in object's 'name' property is used if it
>   exists, or else, the site-defined value for the 'anonymous' variable.
>   However, a module may override this by implementing
>   hook_user_format_name_alter(&$name, $account).
>
> **Return value**
>
> string|\Drupal\Component\Render\MarkupInterface Either a string that
>   will be auto-escaped on output or a MarkupInterface object that is
>   already HTML escaped. Either is safe to be printed within HTML
>   fragments.

Comment: {{ ...author_picture['#user'].name.value }} is showing error,

Comment: `{{ author_picture['#user'].name.value }}` is working correctly, Thanks and pls edit the answer too

Comment: I didn't know what variable you put in kint(), but it seems it is a top level variable, so we can remove the ...