# Reason for adding .value to access node id?

Tags: theming

I was trying to access node id in twig. After debugging for a while I found that `node.nid` was holding the value I wanted. However, when I tried to render using that variable it didn't print anything. After struggling for while I found that I need to append `.value` in the end which obviously worked. But I am not sure reason behind using `.value`. Can someone tell me when and where should we use such?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Because `nid` is a field and you want to get the field value.

Long answer: Node is like User or Taxonomy Term an entity and provides the method `id()`. So instead of accessing the id fields by their individual field name (nid, uid, tid), it's easier and better OOP practice to use the method [EntityInterface::id](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Aid/8.5.x):

```
{{ node.id }}
```

Comment: **Because nid is a field and you want to get the field value.** Ok then how come I don't need to use `.value` when using content, ie `{{ content.field_name }}` ??? My guess is content already ran `$entity->field_name->value` ???

Comment: Yes, in `{{ content.field_name }}` are the field values, but in a render array built by the field formatter you have configured in the view mode.